# Adding Git Bash Here (right click) option with silent install

Tags: git, silent-install

I want to install git silently. But this machine will be developer machine. So I need to have right-click "git bash here" option. I do that "git.exe /VERYSILENT" but it loads git as default. What is the command line for git with git bash here (right-click)option ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use these options

```
git.exe /VERYSILENT /COMPONENTS="icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh"
```

I was able to piece together the options from looking at the code here:
https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/install.iss

Also, the commands for inno setup can be found at:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline